# Create hi-res screenshot of node tree?

Tags: materials, node-editor, image

Is there a way to export (as a high-resolution image or vector file) the node setup of a given material? As I'm setting up some tutoring material I would prefer to avoid screenshots for material with approx. 15 nodes or more.